# Spatial join for multiple shapefiles using loop and ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-join, loop

I have the following two datasets:

- polygon shapefile containing administrative boundaries of a City
- multiple point shapefiles

What I want to do is to spatially join the point shapefiles with the polygon based on the match_option intersect using arcpy. So to say, I want to count the number of Features per Point shapefile in the polygon shapefile. I do not Need any fields of the Point shapefils, but only the join_count field.

This is the Python script I have so far.

```
output = 'F:\\test\\spatialJoin'
pointShpfiles = listofShapefiles.split(";")  
spatialJoin = administrativeUnits
for pointShp in pointShpfiles:  
    spatialJoin = arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(spatialJoin, pointShp, arcpy.Polygon, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL", "dummyField", "INTERSECT")
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(spatialJoin, 'dummyField')
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(spatialJoin, 'TARGET_FID') 
    
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(spatialJoin, output)
```

The script works partly, but the Problem is, that only the last of the Point shapefiles in the list is added, so I only have one join_count field instead of 3 (for three entered Point shapefiles).

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found out why only the current join_count was added. This is due to the dummyField that was added, meaning this was the only field that was preserved, all others were deleted, also the previous join_counts.