# ArcPy Spatial Join Loop use the output layer as the target feature

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-join, loop

I am trying to generate a script that executes a Spatial Join between specific shapefiles.
However the only values that are added to the result feature are the first and last in the list of shapefiles to join.
I have tried different approaches, however the result is always the same.

[Spatial join for multiple shapefiles (loop)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180380) exposes the same problem, however I have not been able to identify the way it was solved.

This is the code:

```py
# Shapefiles to join
selfc = ['tertiary_roads_CO_m_nonoise.shp',
         'tertiary_roads_NOX_m_nonoise.shp', 
         'tertiary_roads_PM10_nonoise.shp',
         'tertiary_roads_PM25_nonoise.shp',
         'tertiary_roads_SO2_nonoise.shp']

# Define target feature as the first element in the selfc list
targetFeature = selfc[0]

joinFeatures  = selfc[1:]
outfc = os.path.join(outdir, "testSpatialJoin")

for feature in joinFeatures:
    #Run the Spatial Join tool
    arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(targetFeature, feature, outfc, "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY", "KEEP_ALL")
```

**Result:** Just the last Shapefile in the `selfc` list is joined to the Target Feature.

[image]

Comment: You need to use the output of each join as input to the next. But it would be easier to merge all joinfeatures then join once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has finally been solved by saving the result of each iteration (as suggested by @BERA) in an `arcpy.Point` object, and at the end of the `For` loop copying each point object generated in a new Feature.

```py
# Shapefiles to join
selfc = ['tertiary_roads_CO_m_nonoise.shp',
         'tertiary_roads_NOX_m_nonoise.shp', 
         'tertiary_roads_PM10_nonoise.shp',
         'tertiary_roads_PM25_nonoise.shp',
         'tertiary_roads_SO2_nonoise.shp']

# Define target feature as the first element in the selfc list
targetFeature = selfc[0]

joinFeatures  = selfc[1:]
outfc = os.path.join(outdir, "testSpatialJoin")

for feature in joinFeatures:
    #Run the Spatial Join tool
    targetFeature = arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(targetFeature, feature, arcpy.Point, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL")

# Copies feature from the iteration to a new feature class.
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(targetFeature, outfc)
```